# How hidden subcategory in topmenu Prestashop 1.7.X in Classic theme?

Tags: css, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i tried to hidden the subcategory and sub-subcategory menu in topmenu horizontal in Clasic Theme Prestashop 1.7.3 but i didnt find the correct code css and php code in tpl. 
If anybody can help me? Only need change the code in css or .tpl too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By CSS is really easy, with google chrome you can do...

1. Right click in the element of the menu you want to hide.
2. Click on **Inspect**
3. Now in the DevTool will be highlighted the element.
4. Do right click on it.
5. In the contextual menu, make click on `Copy > Copy selector`

After this, you will have the CSS selector that you need to hide in your clipboard, just paste it in some style sheet (CSS file) to create your rule to hide the element, something like this:

```
#category-3 > a {
  display: none;
}
```

In some of this style sheets should works:

- `/themes/YOUR_THEME/assets/css/custom.css`
- `/themes/YOUR_THEME/assets/css/theme.css`

Once made, don't forget to clear the cache.